# How to play video INSIDE bash

Tags: python, bash, image-recognition

I want to play videos inside bash that displays a frame by characters. (Just Like ASCII Camera on Android) How do I do that?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.darkside.asciicamfree&hl=en) is what you are referring to you can forget it. I haven't download that app but I'm pretty sure it doesn't even emulate a terminal. 
By the way your question is interesting.

Do this:

```
apt-get install sl
```

and then

```
sl
```

This is the maximum the terminal can do for you: a locomotive that moves. If you are OK with that we can move ahead.

Now install [jp2a](https://csl.name/jp2a/) this way `apt-get install jp2a`
You now can transform images to ASCII text by doing `jp2a --width=150 myimagename.jpg`

So at first your question looked impossible but now we can see that there might be a way out. There are other people [who did that](https://opensource.com/life/16/6/terminal-based-games-linux).

You now need to split a video into `.jpg` images and you can do that thanks to `FFMPG` [this way](https://superuser.com/questions/135117/how-to-convert-video-to-images) . Becarefull, you might easily create more than 25,000 images out of a small video so tune the command...

*[...]Change the %xd to however many digits you need, e.g. if the command would create more than 10,000 frames change the %04d to %05d. This also works for input files that are image sequence. Read more here.*

Well, we are at a good point now:

- We can convert video to .jpg
- We can convert .jpg to ASCII text

You now need to write a script that does it automatically and then try to render the ASCII picture on the terminal like the `sl` locomotive and you are done

Answer (score 1):

If you have `libcaca` installed on your system you can do it with both `mpv` and `mplayer`:

```
mplayer -vo caca samle.avi
```

or

```
mpv --quiet -vo caca sample.avi
```

You could also use `-vo aa` for black & white output. You might need to prepend the command with `DISPLAY=` to trick `caca` to use terminal instead of regular window.

That is, if you media player was compiled with `libcaca` support. You can find out like so:

```
mpv --vo help
```

or

```
mplayer -vo help
```

Comment: Good! or simply do [this](https://dereenigne.org/linux/vlc-caca-ascii-output/) `vlc -V caca fileToOpen`